# cannot override OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a asp.net core mvc web application where I try to add a baseclass and overide OnActionExecuting, but I get the following error...

'BaseController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'Controller.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)' BaseController.cs   9   Active

this is my base class..

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Change `protected` access modifier to `public`:

```cs
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```